# 16x2 Charater display for outdoor use

Tags: lcd, display, oled

I currently have a project installed in an outdoor location.  It currently uses a 16x2 blue OLED display for simple messages to the user.

Over the past 4 years I have had to replace the display twice as it fades to the point of becoming unreadable.  The display mostly only receives indirect sunlight, except for a few hours as the sun sets in the evening.  However, it needs to be readable in bright daylight.

The display is mounted to an enclosure, behind a plexiglass screen.  The interior of the enclosure is kept above 0ºC.  The outdoor ambient temperature can range between -40ºC and +40ºC.

The reason I picked an OLED screen vs. a typical LCD was my worry that the cold temperatures contacting the face of the display would make it unusable.

**Question**

What type of display would be best suited for my project?  Stick with the OLED, switch to a bright LCD, or something else?

Comment: 2 years sounds about right for a OLED display exposed to outside UV. Coating the plexiglass might help.

Comment: Is the display permanently turned on? Or is it off most of the time  and turns on only when keys are pressed?

Comment: Display is currently on 24/7, displaying user instructions.